# Design Pattern, Multi agent system, Robotics

Tags: c++, design-patterns, multi-agent

A short description:

There is 5 robots, and each robot runs a program named "Planner".
Each robot has a post, and they must do a task(select it from many tasks) according to that post. the main loop is (Pseudo code):

```
while(true)
{
   /*1*/ WorldModel::getSingelton()->update();
   /*2*/ Post post = selectAPost();
   /*3*/ Task task = selectATask(&post);
   /*4*/ task.run();
}
```

And, a task may runs another task. In fact inside a task there is a decision tree.

I have many components like: HardwareInterface, VisionInterface, WorldModel, Configuration, NetworkInterface, ... . They all do a part of this system.

**My question is not about algorithms, it's about design-patterns for multi-agent and robotic systems in C++ *(or Java)*.**

Is there any design-pattern for these systems*(multi-agent and robotic systems)*? *or my question is a mistake?*

*Note: My current design pattern is Singleton for managing my components*

Comment: "My current design pattern"? You're not doing this pattern thing correctly. You don't shop for design patterns.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: [Start with design patterns](http://codeshite.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/how-to-become-a-great-software-developer/) ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Do you expect i write my all code (12,000 lines of code) ?! That code in question is just a pseudo-code

Comment: [Watch and be enlightened](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)

Comment: @MasoudM. My comment is advice. I'm warning you that "I need a design pattern for this" is not the correct way to think about design patterns.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I disagree.  How else would you select a design pattern?  Of course you shop for them - you have a problem you want to solve, and then you look for a design pattern that will solve that problem elegantly.  He's looking for such a design pattern.

Comment: @Eric: I don't select design patterns. I look out for solutions to the problem at hand. Sometimes these solutions happen to be very roughly described in a book somewhere. When that happens, it's good because I have an easily recognizable name to use when communicating with my peers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I expect that when you look for solutions to problems, you are essentially "shopping" for design patterns. You do weigh various designs against each other, I'm sure, even if only subconsciously. It seems that the OP differs in that he is directly shopping for pre-established design patterns, whereas more experienced developers, such as yourself, may come upon them by chance or habit.  In general, I think it's perfectly acceptable to look for pre-established design patterns, as many patterns are unintuitive and would otherwise never be used. Best not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Still, the advice of R.MartinhoFernandes is pretty valid in this discussion. First you must understand the problem and then look for a solution, and any pattern that might help as well. Another thing is about the reference of "Start with design patterns" being so lame. @Masoud M. you are right in looking for patterns to solve your problem, but you must state better what is the design challenge you're facing. For instance, you can "buy" the GoF patterns as Template Method, Strategy, Factory, etc. However, you present a solution for your problem, so why do you need extra patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a lot! Three examples of academic works on design patterns for multiagent design:

L. Sabatucci, M. Cossentino, S. Gaglio. A Semantic Description For Agent Design Patterns. In Proc. of the Sixth International Workshop "From Agent Theory to Agent Implementation" (AT2AI-6) at The Seventh International Joint Conference on Autonomous Agents and Multi-Agent Systems (AAMAS 2008), Estoril, Portugal. May, 2008.

Design Patterns for Multiagent Systems Design
Sylvain Sauvage
MICAI 2004: ADVANCES IN ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE
Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 2004, Volume 2972/2004, 352-361, DOI: 10.1007/978-3-540-24694-7_36
http://www.springerlink.com/content/bc32d3lda58rfxaj

Design patterns for self-organizing multiagent systems
by Luca Gardelli ,  Mirko Viroli ,  Andrea Omicini
IN: PROCEEDINGS OF EEDA
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.95.3098

If you look at the past [AAMAS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170411233902/http://aamas2012.webs.upv.es:80/) proceedings you can find much more.